# Profile Memory Between Requests in Rails to Find Leaks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a **Rails 4.2.1** app that has a memory leak. I'm hosting on Heroku and when in production my memory continues to grow until the server starts paging. I'm trying to source out the leak - and wanted to know if there is a way I can debug the memory allocations still active after a request / response. If I can get that, I can `curl` my pages a few times to warm any globals then `siege` to see what memory is leaking. Any way to do  this?

Comment: In regards to the problem itself, what Heroku stack and web server are you running? There have been mentions about possible memory issues with `cedar-14` running `unicorn`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29208169/switching-to-heroku-cedar-14-leads-to-continous-increase-in-memory-consumption

Comment: @Drenmi Running `cedar-14` with `passenger` and `ruby 2.2.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rack-mini-profiler gem allows you to get a count of objects in memory by class (and allocated by the current request). It also dumps some of the most frequent objects such as strings - I've found it very helpful for diagnosing memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've got the `?pp=profile-gc` report up now, but I'm not sure how to read it.  Which metric indicates how many objects were leaked?

Comment: Well if the number of live objects for a class keeps rising then you're probably leaking instances of that class